# Where can I find aquatic maps to explore?

Tags: ros, ros-melodic, scan

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi! Im working with the Heron simulating prototype, and what I need is to be able to use the lidar that has already in its packages. The thing is,I have manage to use it, but the ones provided by Heron are pretty big, and the one called "inspection_world" has already being mapped. Is there any map elsewhere, so I could download and try the laser scan?
If the map is rather small, better!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/393685/where-can-i-find-aquatic-maps-to-explore?/) by [LuisCa](https://answers.ros.org/users/92274/luisca/) on ROS Answers with karma: 23 on 2022-01-03

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi @LuisCa

There is an interesting publication that used Heron robot and trained it with reinforcement learning. New worlds were created and you can use those to test Heron as well. Here is the link to the [paper](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/349520946_How_To_Train_Your_HERON)

The fork of this project can be found: https://github.com/AntoineRichard/Heron-RL-ICRA. However some of the links are not working, so you need to dig a little.

For example the `uuv_simulator/uuv_gazebo_worlds/worlds/` has other worlds available for simulation for example `lake.world`: https://github.com/AntoineRichard/uuv_simulator/tree/master/uuv_gazebo_worlds/worlds

[image: image description]

Not sure about size, but you can modify them for sure.

Also take a look at the `heron_worlds` package that was made to help create world specifically for Heron:
https://github.com/heron/heron_worlds

---

Originally posted by [osilva](https://answers.ros.org/users/84086/osilva/) with karma: 1650 on 2022-01-03

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2